# Does $F-F=[0,1] \mod 1$ imply $\mu F = 1$ for $F$ with positive Lebesgue measure?

Tags: measure-theory

This question has come up while playing around with the Steinhaus theorem:

Let $F-F$ denote the algebraic difference $\{f-g \mod 1 | f,g \in F\}$. Suppose that $F\subset[0,1]$ with $\mu F>0$ , where $\mu$ is the usual Lebesgue measure. If we know that $F-F = [0,1]$, may we conclude that $\mu F = 1$?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: So you are looking for a converse to Steinhaus? No, not true, try $F=$ Cantor set.

Comment: @Lubin, OP asks for example with positive Lebesgue measure. Of course, your example is easily modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple counter-example: $F=[0,\frac{1}{2}]$.

Comment: Thanks richard! Should've seen something so straightforward.